# How to incrementally search for files in a website?

Tags: html, server, directory

this is a hypothetical question for an intro to servers course.

Say you want to search for all available .txt files in a web directory such as

http://xyz123madeupname.com/files

A .txt file that is available to you is called  http://xyz123madeupwebsitename.com/files/1256

Another .txt file that is available to you is called http://xyz123madeupwebsitename.com/files/1795

You want to find out what other files are available to you from this directory.

How would you do that without manually entering a number and checking to see if a .txt file is available to you? Is there a tool you could use to incrementally check files/1 to 2000 and see if there is a .txt at that page?

Thanks,

Buddy

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. If the web server has been configured correctly it will serve a default document, and if that document is found in the folder, that's what you'll get. You can't make a request that says "show me your directory tree." because of permission and security implications. So anything professionally coded won't let you do this. Many sites deliberately dispense with the robots.txt file because it could tell attackers where things like scripts are located. (Many other sites just forget to create one, of course.) See [Directory traversal attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack), [Robots.txt](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt)